# Parsing JSON into Core Data objects in the background

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, magicalrecord

I have a JSON response that looks like this (simplified):

```
houses: [
    {
        id: "1",
        color: "red",
        windows: [ 
            {
                id: "1",
                type: "large",
                numPanes: 3
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                type: "small",
                numPanes: 2
            },
        ],
        doors: [ 
            {
                id: "33",
                size: "large",
                color: "gray"
            },
            {
                id: "12",
                size: "large",
                color: "blue"
            },
        ],

    },
    {
        id: "2",
        color: "purple",
        windows: [ 
            {
                id: "6",
                type: "medium",
                numPanes: 4
            },
            {
                id: "8",
                type: "small",
                numPanes: 2
            },
        ],
        doors: [ 
            {
                id: "38",
                size: "large",
                color: "green"
            },
            {
                id: "42",
                size: "large",
                color: "orange"
            },
        ],

    }
]
```

I need to save each house in Core Data and display them all, say in a table view. Right now I'm doing something like this:

```
for each house:
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    ...set properties of the House entity
    [house save:context];
    for each window
         NSManagedObjectContext* context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
        ...set properties of the Window entity
        [window save:context];
        [house addWindowObject:window];
    for each door
         NSManagedObjectContext* context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
        ...set properties of the Door entity
        [door save:context];
        [house addDoorObject:door];
    [house save];
```

The save method looks like this:

```
- (void)save:(NSManagedObjectContext *)context {
    if (context == nil) {
        context = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];
    }

    [context MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError* error) {

    }];
}
```

The problem is that all this Core Data saving seems to be blocking the main thread, and as new Houses are read in from the feed and processed into Core Data, the scrollview gets choppy. Time Profiler seems to point to the save method as something that's taking some processor time.

I am using MagicalRecord, but I think the question applies even if I wasn't. How can I structure the data processing so as to not block the main thread?

The view controller that displays the houses looks like this when it gets a new batch of houses:

```
for (NSDictionary* houseInfo in houses) {
    House* house = [DataManager houseFromJSON:houseInfo];
    [_houseData addObject:house];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We've just update MagicalRecord with some fixes that should address the issue of blocking the main thread on save. [Have a look](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/releases/tag/2.3.0-beta.2).

Comment: For those of us not using Magical Record, can you describe the changes you made? It's not to answer the original question but may be of educational benefit for the community.

Comment: @casademora thanks for the tip. It would be great if updating MR "magically" fixed the problem. I'll try it. I don't see anything about background issues or blocking the main thread in the release notes though. Was that in a previous version? Also, how can I tell which version I'm using?

Comment: @Tommy I would, however, I'm not exactly sure of what the fix was at the moment.